# Mediations in AdMob. Understanding them better

Tags: admob, ads

I am trying to ad Mediation in Admob for other ad networks. Now I have many doubts regarding mediation. I am putting them point-wise. Please explain if possible.

1. When we add mediation network to Admob, suppose InMobi, do we have
   to add SDK and other manifest and code changes in the app to make it
   work.?
2. How do we find that the current Ad is being displayed from InMobi(or any other Ad network.).?
3. Suppose InMobi Ads are displayed in the App by Admob, will this be also updated in the dashboard of InMobi account or just Admob
   will be updated.?
4. How to set the **eCPM** value for added networks.

Please explain if you know even one point of these.

Answer (score 2):

1. You will need to add the Inmobi SDK + any adapter that Inmobi has created between Admob and Inmobi. You may also need to create an Inmobi Ad Activity in your Manifest.
2. There is no easy way. Viewing the log can sometimes provide that info.
3. The Admob mediation dashboard will be updated and the Inmodi ad dashboard will be updated.
4. AdMob provides the ability to have the eCPM auto set based upon past peformance by each ad network. I strongly recommend you use it to maximise your revenue.

To clarify the 4th point.

In the Admob dashboard when you edit your mediation, if you check "Optimize AdMob metwork" then Admob will insert itself in the mediation chain based upon past performance.

Likewise for each ad source (in the mediation) when you edit them you can check "Automatically pull the eCPM value from this ad network" which will gather current stats from that network and use it to position that network in the mediation chain.

Comment: Do we also need to do the coding part.?

Comment: You only need to code the Admob AdView. It is then used to display ads from all ad networks.

Comment: What do the 4th point mean.. Is that the default value shows when we setup the mediation

Comment: Hello William. I want to ask you that I was previously using Admob ads which works perfectly. and now I want to use Admob Mediation And I create account on MOBFOX and add its Jar Adapter to my libs and add SDK activity in my menifest. what I have to do next ? 
is it compulsory to add its SDK code. if yes then should I replace the Admob Adview and InterstitialAd objects with MOBFOX. and If I replace it with MobFox datatypes then how it will show simple admob ads.?

Comment: @ArslanMaqbool You shouldn't need to change your code. All you should need to do is include the MobFox library in your APK and create a MobFox option in your mediation list on the Admob portal.